# Where should the preferred DNS server be in a LAN?

Tags: domain-name-system, router, local-area-network

I had a hard time formulating this question’s title, but I think I’ve stated it correctly.  My question may stem from a misunderstanding, so I will explain what happened to cause me to think I might have things incorrectly setup.

**The system**:

There is currently a single physical Dell server running hyper-V to host all the servers in the development system.  All servers are 2012 R2.  The primary domain controller (also a DNS) is on this physical Dell host, along with all the other servers such as TFS, IIS, SQL, etc.  There is a second PC as a client workstation and it is also running hyper-V on which there is a second domain controller (also a DNS).  The LAN router is a Cisco small business router and it is configured to handle the DHCP for the system.  (Another discrete physical server will be added when I can but this is the best I can do right now).  Although the system is small at present, I want to set it up correctly for the future when more servers and clients are added.

**What occurred**:

I set all my servers to use static IP’s; all clients use dynamic IP’s.  When I try to join a new server to the domain, I note that the Preferred DNS server IP on the new server must be set to point to a domain controller or the new server can’t find the domain in order to attach to the domain.  That makes sense to me because the domain name has to be resolved to one of domain controllers in order to communicate for attaching.  Is this a misunderstanding?

**Should the preferred DNS IP be something other than one of my domain controllers**?

Assuming I did not misunderstand as described above, it then occurred to me I might not be setting up DNS properly in my LAN.  Since best practice tells me to have a minimum of 2 domain controllers and multiple DNS and I can certainly have more, where/who should the Preferred DNS server be?  For clients using DHCP, the DNS will be set automatically.  But for my static IP servers I have to point somewhere for the Preferred/Alternate DNS servers.  I can only list 2 IP addresses on a given Ethernet connection, so if those 2 DNS failed for some reason, even if I had a third DNS working I will still lose local DNS, yes?

So then I thought perhaps I should be using my Cisco LAN router as the Preferred DNS server and entering every one of my LAN domain controllers in its table so that no matter how many domain controllers fail, all clients will be able to find a local DNS as long as one domain controller is alive. (This is assuming every domain controller is also a DNS).  Or is it a misunderstanding to think the LAN router is a reasonable device to be the Preferred DNS?

That’s why I ask where the preferred DNS should be in a LAN that requires local name resolution.  Should the Preferred DNS server be the LAN router or is there a better standard best practice to accomplish this differently?

In my Server Fault research before asking this question, I read about loopback IP’s, but I don’t understand why I need that.  If I point to a Preferred DNS that lists all the DNS servers in my system and also includes a pointer to my ISP do I still need a loopback IP entered in any of the domain controller Ethernet adapter’s properties?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're over thinking things a bit, but your basic understanding is correct.

You should have at least two Domain Controllers (in your scenario two should be sufficient).

The Domain Controllers should also be DNS servers and should host the AD DNS zone (this isn't a requirement but it's the easiest deployment method for DC's and DNS).

**ALL** domain clients (including all servers, workstations, virtual machines and the Domain Controllers themselves) should **ONLY** use the AD DNS servers for preferred and alternate DNS. They should **NEVER** use any non-AD DNS servers for DNS (never is a strong position to take but in your scenario just work from this premise).

Dump the idea of using the Cisco router for DNS. I'm not even going to try to understand how this might work. Just don't do it. If both DC/DNS servers fail simultaneously you'll have bigger things to worry about then DNS resolution.

Comment: I do over think sometimes so thanks for pulling me back from the abyss...  So for each static IP server (not the DC's), would the Preferred and Alternate DNS server IP's be the IP's for DC1 & DC2 respectively?  And then inside DC1 & DC2 is the Preferred DNS supposed to be the 'other' DCx (as I saw in a different Serverfault post)? And then are the DCs Alternate DNS's supposed to point to the LAN router which is the gateway to my ISP and has its DNS pointing to the ISP or am I supposed to add the ISP DNS a different way?

Comment: For each DC it should use it's partner DC for primary DNS and itself for secondary DNS. Add 127.0.0.1 as tertiary DNS on each DC.

Comment: You can add the ISP DNS servers as forwarders in the DNS server properties or you can use root hints without forwarders, I prefer the latter.

Comment: Regarding the tertiary DNS of 127.0.0.1; is that basically just 'dns insurance', or is there something deeper happening?  And I may have thought this was more involved, but is entering the tertiary DNS as simple as using the Advanced button to get to the Advanced TCP/IP Settings panel and just adding that IP on the DNS tab?

Comment: Yes, it is that simple to add 127.0.0.1 as tertiary DNS. Doing this is considered a best practice from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1):

For a Windows 2000 or later Windows domain, you have to have a Windows DNS server available for all machines that are joined or want to join. Your AD integrated DNS servers do not have to also be your domain controllers, but you must have at least one and members of the domain should use *only* you internal AD integrated DNS servers.

I'm going to say that again just to be clear:
For servers and workstations joined to the domain, their lists of DNS servers should *only* consist of AD integrated Windows DNS servers that contain the domain records. They should not have any external DNS servers or non-windows internal DNS servers listed.

Also in Windows you can have more than two DNS servers listed. For a local static configuration, click the "Advanced" button under IPv4 properties. On most DHCP servers you can easily list more than two DNS servers.